# Reverse strings without changing the order of words in a sentence

Tags: javascript

My Code:

I tried the following code but the order of words are changing

```
var str = "Welcome to my Website !";

alert(str.split("").reverse().join(""));
```

It is giving result as

`! etisbeW ym ot emocleW`

But I need the result as

`emocleW ot ym etisbeW !`

That is, I don't want to change the order of words.

Comment: I have no knowledge in Java or Javascript, so I should not comment anything here. But I have one advice for you instead of using `inbuilt function call` try to do the same in `without` using `inbuilt function call`, that will enhance your logical thinking. Anyhow Good Luck

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak, not a solution nor approach for the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this:

```
var str = "Welcome to my Website !";
alert(str.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" "));
```

Comment: Short and Sweet. Working Perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Wondering, actually how it is working as expected within one line of statement?

Comment: It is just reversing the whole sentences first and then split with spaces and then reversing so that the words can be sorted in expected order.

Comment: so how can i do "! Website my to Welcome" ? @Md.MahbubulHaque

Answer (score 11):

You can split on spaces, and then use `map` to reverse the letters in each word:

```
alert(str.split(" ").map(function(x) {
    return x.split("").reverse().join("");
}).join(" "));​
```

Comment: Note: only in newer browsers. (Which I don't care about, screw old browser users anyway. But you might.)

Answer (score 5):

For older browser support you can try this,

```
var str = "Welcome to my Website !";

String.prototype.str_reverse= function(){
 return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var arr = str.split(" ");
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
 arr[i] = arr[i].str_reverse();
}

alert(arr.join(" ")); //OUTPUT: emocleW ot ym etisbeW !
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this using a functional approach and typescript:

```
const  aString = "Our life always expresses the result of our dominant thoughts.";

function reverseString (str: string) :string {
  return  str.split('').reverse().join('')
}

function reverseWords(str:string) :string {
  return str.split(" ").map(reverseString).join(" ")
}

console.log(reverseWords(aString))
// ruO efil syawla sesserpxe eht tluser fo ruo tnanimod .sthguoht
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using:

`[...word].reverse().join('')`

Which in my opinion is a little bit cleaner

`[...word]` - makes an array out of string

`.reverse()` - reverses the array

`.join('')` - joins the array into a string

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> you can use user-defined reverse function instead of using `split` and
> `join` multiple times.

```
function strReverse(str) {
    let reverseString = "";
    for (let i = str.length; i >= 0; i--) {
      reverseString += str[i];
    }
    return reverseString;
}

const str = "Welcome to my website !";
str
    .split(" ")
    .map((s) => strReverse(s))
    .join(" ");
```