# reverse a string in Javascript using unshift function

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

Can anyone explain what's the mistake in the below code?

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let reversedStr = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    reversedStr.unshift(str[i]);
    return str;
  }
}
console.log(
 reverseString("hello")
 )
```

Comment: `unshift` is a function that lives on the Array prototype, not String. Also, you're returning from the loop after only the first iteration.

Comment: Did you get this as an interview question?

Comment: Related to this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/13737432/104380

Answer (score 0):

You need an array to do unshift and the return outside the loop

```js
const reverseString = str => {
  const rev = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) rev.unshift(str[i])
  return rev.join("")
};
console.log(
  reverseString("hello")
)
```

but here is a oneliner

```js
const reverseString = str => str ? [...str].reverse().join("") : str;

console.log(
  reverseString("hello")
)
```

Comment: _"but here is a oneliner"_ - that is part of **every** question that asks for the same topic: [how to reverse a string?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+string+reverse+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Andreas and? This was how to use unshift which is not a very useful method, so I added a more efficient version

Answer (score 0):

#### Using unshift method

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    arr.unshift(str[i]);
  }
  return arr.join("");
}
console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

#### Alternative

If you meant to do the string reverse without using a util function, you can do it like below. If the string length is `n` then the time complexity of the below code is `O(n/2)`.

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  // get single characters into array
  const arrOfChars = str.split("");
  // get the half size of the array
  const halfLengthOfArr = Math.floor(arrOfChars.length / 2);
  // start index
  let i = 0;
  // swap chars until reach the middle of the array
  // h e l l o
  // ^       ^
  // o e l l h
  //   ^   ^
  // o l l e h
  while (i < halfLengthOfArr) {
    // swap coupterparts from start and end with same distance
    const start = arrOfChars[i];
    arrOfChars[i] = arrOfChars[arrOfChars.length - (i + 1)];
    arrOfChars[arrOfChars.length - (i + 1)] = start;
    i++;
  }
  // return the output array as a string
  return arrOfChars.join("");
}
console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend completely going away from the unshift approach based on your requirement.

Therefore, I've designed two versions of your function for you and all are based purely on array functions.

Compact version:

```
function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("")
}

console.log(
    reverseString("hello")
)
```

Longer version (easier to understand):

```
function reverseString(str) {
    const characters = str.split("")
    const charactersReversed = characters.reverse()
    return charactersReversed.join("")
}

console.log( reverseString("hello") )
```

I hope that helped, even if I don't address your unshift request.

Last but not least, I've also reworked your initial code with your unshift function, even if I don't recommend this code in production:

```
function reverseString(str) {
    const reversedStr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        reversedStr.unshift(str[i]);
    }
    return reversedStr.join("");
}

console.log(
   reverseString("hello")
)
```

Comment: What does this add to the other two answers?

Comment: Simply giving someone who is learning JavaScript another way of solving his issue. What is so wrong with it?

Comment: But you did not... Your answers are identical to others on the page

Comment: You want me to delete it?

Comment: Just curious if you saw the answers posted 3 hours before yours

Comment: I somehow have missed it.